# Cross-platform notification that a service is running

Tags: c++, cross-platform, ipc

I am looking for a cross platform method of notifying several client applications that a service/daemon has started and is able to handle incoming connections. The clients will be running all the time, whereas the service may not. Normally the service/daemon will be started automatically when the computer starts, but in some cases it may not and in those cases the clients should automatically connect when the service/daemon starts.

The basic flow of the client is to wait until they notice that the service is running, then connect. If the connection is interrupted or if they were unable to connect they just try again from the beginning.

For Windows I have a solution where the service signals a global event object when it starts so that the clients can wait on this event. This works ok in reality, but I am pretty sure that it does not handle all potential cases (such as a crashing service or multiple instances of the service running). I don't mind if the clients "accidentally" wake up every now and then even though the service isn't running. I just want to avoid that the clients enter a busy loop trying to connect all the time, while at the same time respond pretty quickly to the service starting. I.e. just adding a sleep between connection attempts is not great.

**Is there a cross platform method to detect whether the service is running and ready to accept connections?**

**Update:** I'll add a bit more information on how the current mechanism works on Windows using approximate code from memory, so please excuse any typos:

Service:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
// Set up empty SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES so that everyone has access
// ...

// Create a manual reset event, initially set to nonsignaled
HANDLE event = ::CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, "Global\\unique_name");

// Signal the event - service is running and ready
::SetEvent(event);

// Handle connections, do work

// If the service dies for whatever reason, Windows deletes the event handle
// The event is deleted when the last open handle to it is closed
// So the event is signaled for at least as long as the service lives
```

Clients:

```
while (true) {
    // Set up event the same way as the service, including empty security attributes
    // ...
    HANDLE event = ::CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, "Global\\unique_name");

    // Wait for the service to start
    DWORD ret = ::WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE);

    // Close the handle to avoid keeping the event object alive
    // This isn´t enough in theory, but works in real usage as the number of clients
    // will always be low
    ::CloseHandle(event);

    // Check if we woke up because the event is signaled
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == ret) {
        // connect to service, do work
        // ...
    }
}
```

**How could I achieve approximately the same on OS X and Linux?**

Comment: You can simply try to broadcast the information accross the network

Comment: @Geoffroy: This will be within one machine only.

Comment: Then update the modification time of a file, or create it, and make other programs monitor the directory